# How can I trap process exits in yaws?

Tags: erlang, yaws

A separate **Erlang** chat server stores all `PIDs` in a `mnesia` table and groups them under a Room ID so when a user sends a message, A `gen_server` sends the message to all processes under that Room ID.

so far everything works great but the problem is:

When the user subscribes to the server, The server sends  a message to all `pids` to notify subscribers about a new subscriber, however I cannot think of/know a practical way to do reverse of it.

I need to let people know that a subscriber has unsubscribed and remove the pid from the table. How can I implement such `supervsor` in yaws?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the server sends a message to all pids to notify them of a new subscriber, have it also notify a process whose job is to [`erlang:monitor/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#monitor-2) each new subscriber process. That process, a `gen_server`, could keep a table of some sort as its state, like a `map`, `dict`, or `ets` table, that stores the reference returned from `erlang:monitor/2` along with the associated room ID. When a subscriber process dies, the monitor process will receive a `{'DOWN', MonitorRef, Type, Object, Info}` message via its [`gen_server:handle_info/2` function](http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html#Module:handle_info-2), and it can then look up the `MonitorRef` in its state and notify the associated room of the dropped subscription.